# Create single dictionary with jq

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I have the following input:

```
[
  {
    constant_id: 5,
    object_id: 2,
    object_type: 'delimited_file',
    name: 'data_file_pattern',
    value: 'list_of_orders.csv',
    insert_date: 2021-11-23T10:24:16.568Z,
    update_date: null
  },
  {
    constant_id: 6,
    object_id: 2,
    object_type: 'delimited_file',
    name: 'header_count',
    value: '1',
    insert_date: 2021-11-23T10:24:16.568Z,
    update_date: null
  }
]
```

That I'd like to combine to get the following result:

```
{
  data_file_pattern: 'list_of_orders.csv',
  header_count: '1'
}
```

Basically creating a single dictionary with only the `name` and `value` keys from the input dictionaries. I believe I've done this before but for the life of me I can't figure it out again.

Answer (score 1):

If you get your quoting right in the input JSON, it's as simple as calling the `from_entries` builtin. It converts an array of objects to a single object with given key/value pairs. It takes the field name from a field called `key`, `Key`, `name` or `Name` and the value from a field called `value` or `Value` (see [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Pjp12A-D_5)):

```
from_entries
```

```json
{
  "data_file_pattern": "list_of_orders.csv",
  "header_count": "1"
}
```

Note: I believe the second field name should read `header_count` instead of `delimited_file` as you wanted to take its name from `.name`, not `.object_type`.